# Firebase multiple where clauses using equalsTo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of all the keys I want to download from Firebase. For this I'm using this code:

```
Query newUidsQuery = FirebaseDatabaseHelper.getUsersReference();
newUidsQuery.orderByChild(DATABASE_NODE_USER_UID);
        for (String uid : uidList) {
            newUidsQuery.equalTo(uid);
        }

newUidsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent();
```

This is my current structure:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "5mvsiNKz2hO4rmcDDNskv855dkB3" : {
      "contacts" : [ "GG8JeRNOIhb1qloZb4oCAb7Jd593", "gc0ci7Jgu2QpVYFbeiMJfVy1WHP2" ],
      "contactsHash" : -224276455,
      "email" : "lung.razvan@yahoo.com",
      "name" : "Razvan Cristian Lung",
      "photoUrl" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bItm3-ieAtU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAALZo/mtPyAMohOvg/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "uid" : "5mvsiNKz2hO4rmcDDNskv855dkB3"
    },
    "GG8JeRNOIhb1qloZb4oCAb7Jd593" : {
      "contactsHash" : 1,
      "email" : "andralung@yahoo.com",
      "name" : "Andra Florina Lung",
      "photoUrl" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-po2yelyi3mY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAQ5s/ROefxP6Q1oA/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "uid" : "GG8JeRNOIhb1qloZb4oCAb7Jd593"
    },
    "gc0ci7Jgu2QpVYFbeiMJfVy1WHP2" : {
      "contactsHash" : 1,
      "email" : "lung_razvan2100@yahoo.com",
      "name" : "Lung Razvan",
      "photoUrl" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/15390976_1192204140865562_3397773349261436244_n.jpg?oh=d61795a8df67d3e9c5ddf60557e9e60c&oe=59270863",
      "uid" : "gc0ci7Jgu2QpVYFbeiMJfVy1WHP2"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to get only the entries with the specific key I also get the other entries that have that key as a value in the "contacts" field.

Comment: Try replacing `orderByChild` with `orderByKey()`. Is that the result that you want?

Comment: same result, in fact that was my first try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `orderBy...` or other methods, it returns a new query. So you're now creating a new query for each `uid` that you then don't use. To keep it, you'd need `newUidsQuery = newUidsQuery.equalTo(uid)`.

But that won't solve the problem yet, because a query can only order/filter on a single property and value. See [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase).

Better news is that this doesn't matter much here, since you can just retrieve the items one at a time. Unlike what you might expect, that's not significantly slower than retrieving them in one go. See [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) or watch this episode of #AskFirebase: https://youtu.be/66lDSYtyils?t=1m49s

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've taken the Firebase in a Weekend course and I really liked it and I saw that FireCast. Thanks again. The thing is that I need to get then all at one because I want to update a RecyclerView Adapter. And I don't want to send and update request every time a new item arrives. But if this is not possible I will stick with calling one by one. Thanks again, Puff! "Evanghelos" :))

Comment: lol... that Evanghelos thing will haunt me for years. :-) .   FirebaseUI has an example adapter for handling these joins: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data